# Convert strings to booleans

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I need to import data from excel to access. The importation is now "working" for the obvious types (string, integers). However, In the excel file i have some strings that i need to convert to boolean in my access tables. The strings can take only 2 values "oui" or "non" (yes or no in french).
In my vba code i have the following line:

```
cSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strTable & " ( [N_CLIENT], [NOM_CLI], ) VALUES (" & Chr(34) & .Range("A" & i) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & .Range("F" & i) & Chr(34) & ");"
        
                DoCmd.RunSQL cSQL
```

I would liketo know if i can use an if condition to check the value itself inside the cSQL call and replace it with either true or false. like what follows.

```
cSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strTable & " ( [N_CLIENT], [NOM_CLI], ) VALUES (If(" & Chr(34) & .Range("A" & i) & Chr(34) & " = "oui") then "true" else then "false"," & Chr(34) & .Range("F" & i) & Chr(34) & ");"
        
                DoCmd.RunSQL cSQL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to use apostrophes rather than Chr(34), and splitting the statement across lines using the line-continuation character '_' helps to read the statement. The `IIf()` function is also used in the following.

Also note that you have an extra comma after the term [NOM_CLI] which shouldn't be there.

```
    cSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strTable & "( [N_CLIENT], [NOM_CLI] ) VALUES ('" _
    & IIf(StrComp(.Range("A" & i), "oui", 1) = 0, "true", "false") _
    & "','" & .Range("F" & i) & "');"
```

This results in a string like this:

```
INSERT INTO ( [N_CLIENT], [NOM_CLI] ) VALUES ('true','hello');
```

To use the Boolean values (0, -1) change to:

```
    cSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strTable & "( [N_CLIENT], [NOM_CLI] ) VALUES (" _
    & IIf(StrComp(.Range("A" & i), "oui", 1) = 0, -1, 0) _
    & ",'" & .Range("F" & i) & "');"
```

which yields

```
INSERT INTO ( [N_CLIENT], [NOM_CLI] ) VALUES (-1,'hello');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the extra come is just the result of a copy past of a portion of the code. The use of True/False or -1, 0 will wield to the same result as i need the value to fill a checkbox in my table in access

Answer (score 1):

You can use VBA-Functions in Access-SQL-Queries:

```
"[...] VALUES(strcomp('" & Range("A" & i) & "','oui', 1)=0 [...]"
```

Regards,

AKDA

Comment: If i am not mistaken, The value 0 associated to a boolean in access is false, and -1 is true. In that case should i asume that the 1 you use with strcomp is the value returned when the 2 strings are not equal (False)?

Comment: no, strcomp returns the position of the first mismatch, that means it returns 0 if the two strings are equal and a value > 0 if the strings are **NOT** equal

Comment: So in this case, I still need to use the If statement along with the strcomp to act accordingly to the value returned by strcomp? 
cSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strTable & " ( [N_CLIENT], [NOM_CLI], ) VALUES (" & Chr(34) If (strcomp('" & Range("A" & i) & "','oui', 1)=0)  then "true" else then "false") & Chr(34) &" ....

Comment: in fact strcomp does not return a position; it returns -1 if string1 < string2, 0 if both the same, 1 if string2 > string1 or null if either string is null

Comment: I am still stuck in this case, How am i suppoed to use the if whitin the sql request in vba

Comment: strcomp(..)=0 will return a boolean, so you will not need an **if**-statement

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the Access SQL to evaluate your oui / non into true and false. You could do this using the iif statement http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php. However, why bother? You could just evaluate the range in vba and pass through the boolean variable. Using something like this:

```
dim result as boolean
if sheet1.Range("A" & i) = "oui" then
    result = true
else
    result = false
end if
```

Then just insert that into your SQL:

```
cSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strTable & " ( [N_CLIENT], [NOM_CLI], ) VALUES (If(" & Chr(34) & result & Chr(34) & , & Chr(34) & .Range("F" & i) & Chr(34) & ");"
```

Comment: The VBA code i have will be tailored for many tables, and some tables have more than one boolean field. Also, the i in Range("a" & i) is a counter. this is why i need to do it differently

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the IIF statement in SQL to check the value:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx